# Google on toggled content

Tags: seo, google, content

I have optimized a website and have included toggled content. By toggled content I mean content that becomes visible after clicking a link (Expand and Collaps). The code is as followings:

```
<li id="article-1"> 
<h3><a href="" onClick="$('#article-1 p').not(':first').toggle(); return false;">Article title</a></h3> 
<p>First paragraph</p> 
<p>Second paragraph</p> 
<p>Third paragraph</p> 
</li>
```

Would Google consider this content less valuable since it is not 'directly' visible? Are there any key concepts to keep in mind when working with toggled content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This content isn't special, good or bad, in any way. The only time hidden content becomes a problem is when it is hidden for sole purpose of manipulating the search results.

Comment: In that case, would the position of the content on the page effect the value of that content. Similar to keywords in the title?

Comment: Some people will say yes. Some people will say no. I'll say either way it doesn't matter. If it does have value it will be very small and not worth going out of your way to do and possibly making your site more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

*Would Google consider this content less valuable since it is not 'directly' visible?*

No.

*Are there any key concepts to keep in mind when working with toggled content?*

Yes, the main one is making sure your content can be indexed, which you're already concerned about. The secondary one is usability. You should put yourself in the position of someone using all types of browsers on various kinds of platforms, including mobile, and find out if that content is both visible and accessible to all the people you want to reach.